# Unable to run the following code using python bindings for vlc

Tags: python, python-2.7, vlc

I started with Python Bindings for the first time with:
operating system- ubuntu 14.04
vlc-1.1.2 and python-2.7.6
Here is the sample code I am working on:

```
import vlc 
instance = vlc.Instance()
media_ply = instance.media_player_new()
media_ply.set_mrl("test1.mp3")
media_ply.play()
```

But I am constantly getting the following error message:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "vlc1.py", line 3, in <module>
 instance = vlc.Instance()
 File "/home/ankita/env2/mmenv5/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/vlc.py",                line 1551, in __new__
 return libvlc_new(len(args), args)
 File "/home/ankita/env2/mmenv5/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/vlc.py",        line 3903, in libvlc_new
 ctypes.c_void_p, ctypes.c_int, ListPOINTER(ctypes.c_char_p))
 File "/home/ankita/env2/mmenv5/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/vlc.py", line 246, in _Cfunction
 raise NameError('no function %r' % (name,))
 NameError: no function 'libvlc_new'
```

Can anybody tell me , did I do something wrong?

Answer (score 22):

I was getting same error. Then I solved it by installing vlc (stupid mistake :D) using

```sh
sudo apt-get install vlc
```

Comment: I was fooled for a while since I knew VLC was installed. But via Snap, which didn't do the job

Answer (score 2):

download `vlc.py` from [vlc.py](http://git.videolan.org/?p=vlc/bindings/python.git;a=tree;f=generated;b=HEAD)

Place `vlc.py` in the same directory as your program.

Note that you must have the **VLC Media Player** program already installed on your system.

To test it quickly in python:

```
>>> import vlc
>>> p=vlc.MediaPlayer('test1.mp3')
>>> p.play()
```

Answer (score 0):

Although @aquaman answer is correct if for some reason you have installed vlc but still getting error:

```
NameError: no function 'libvlc_new'
```

check on how you have installed vlc. Snap installed versions of vlc are not useful in this case and should be removed and replaced by the apt-get version:

This should be fine:

```
locate libvlc
```

> /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libvlc.so.5
> /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libvlc.so.5.6.0
> /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libvlccore.so.9
> ...

But this one is not:

```
locate libvlc
```

> /snap/vlc/2288/usr/lib/libvlc.so
> /snap/vlc/2288/usr/lib/libvlc.so.5
> /snap/vlc/2288/usr/lib/libvlc.so.5.6.0
> ..

If that's the case:

```
snap info vlc
sudo apt-get install vlc
```

typically the apt version is older than the snap one so this should also be taken into consideration.