# I keep getting an error when trying to play a video with Vic python

Tags: python, video, vlc

Whenever I run the code in Python, it gives me an error on line 3. I am using VLC with Python in Replit.com, if anyone can help then please answer. Thanks!

Code:

```
import vlc

media = vlc.MediaPlayer("quandale_dingle.mp4")

media.play()
```

(The image below is for Chris from the comments, thanks for telling me what to do, as I am new.)

[Image for Chris](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A87Ql.jpg)

Comment: "An error" is not helpful. Please copy and paste the complete, exact error message.

Comment: @Chris Thanks for telling me this as I am new. I posted the image into the original post, because I cannot copy and paste on Replit’s console I don’t think.

Comment: I don't use Repl.it, but [it looks like you can copy from the console via context menu](https://replit.com/talk/learn/How-to-copy-and-past-in-replit/113146). I'm guessing you're on a phone based on that screenshot; see if long-pressing works.

Comment: In any case, I doubt that whatever system hosts Repl.it [has VLC installed](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41394040/354577). Even if it did, it wouldn't play on _your_ machine, it would play on some machine in a data centre somewhere.

Comment: @Chris Sorry for the late response. Thanks for your help, I will try to do some stuff to fix it, and if it does not work I might have to do Tkinter if I can. And yes, I am on a mobile device (iPad).